# Handle offline http request client-side via queuing mechanism

Tags: javascript, android, http, mobile

So here is the problem statement.

I'm currently working on a hybrid mobile app(using ng-cordova) where I'm supposed to offline mode support, everything is working fine until it comes to making a $http request in offline mode (example: updating status of an employee). Change has been updated in local database but I want to send all these requests as soon as mobile connect to internet. I have tried $http interceptor but it doesn't persist the requests if application gets refreshed. Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem and I think have a great solution... All the app's that works with server have a sync, right? This sync have classic and obligatory statement, our app have internet? The first question and condicional that need it all syncs is this one. Then when this first part of my sync detects that the device don't have the internet my app throws this method:

```
public void ThrowPendingThread(final Activity context){
    if(pendingInformation == null || !pendingInformation.isAlive()) {
        pendingInformation = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            MainActivity.CanUpdate = true;
                            SecondSync_ReceiveInfo(context);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            Log.e("-- Sync_Class.SecondSync_Class --", "Time to sleep!!");
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("-- Sync_Class.SecondSync_Class --", "Exception", ex);
                }
            }
        });

        pendingInformation.start();
    }
}
```

This method at first step, checks if this thread is activates/alive if not exist then throw it. When this thread runs every 10 secs check the connection of our device and when detect internet then throws our sync and stops the thread. This is background process that works if our app is in second plane too...

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Comment: Merli Perez:: thanks for sharing your knowledge but i am trying to find a javaScript solution,  preferably AngularJs . as this is a hybrid app.

Comment: Use the similar concept but with JScript! In java script you hace threads no? :)

Comment: Actually i have solved this problem but with brute force method. I am storing all  requests object with a flag in localStorage and then using setTimeInterval. I am making request whenever device is connected to internet and localStorage has object with  flag=="open" requests, but i am looking for a cleaner and better solution.